# IE 8 make a fullscreen window

Tags: javascript

In Javascript into a LAN I want to make a window completely fullscreen (Kiosk mode)
but I think for security reasons IE 8 always display title bar and location bar.

Does it exsist a way to do that? I'm into a LAN and so no matter if a user is warned about
that.

In Firefox we can force that enabling security privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a programmatical way, but starting IE with

```
iexplore -k www.stackoverflow.com
```

works for me (IE 8, Windows 7).

More info: [**How to use kiosk mode with Internet Explorer?**](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/636-how-to-use-kiosk-mode-with-internet-explorer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have done a web application and so every user must run it in fullscreen mode programmatically.

Comment: @xdevel200 Right. I think that is not possible at all any more - it used to be back when IE 5 was around, but the feature's been abandoned for security reasons. I'm interested to see whether anything comes up.

Comment: So `fullscreen=yes` is no longer supported? http://forums.htmlcenter.com/programming-scripting/148-f11-full-screen-webpage.html#post708

Comment: @Marcel AFAIK, no, it used to work but won't anymore. Might be worth a try whether it works for local / trusted sites but I think it's disabled even there.